# I'm getting error in my program

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, intellij-idea

I'm getting this error:

```
Information:Using javac 1.8.0 to compile java sources
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'HelloWorld'
Information:Compilation completed with 2 errors and 0 warnings in 6 sec
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
C:\Users\Raj\IdeaProjects\HelloWorld\src\CopyCharacters.java
Error:(18, 29) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable c
  location: class CopyCharacters
Error:(21, 30) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable c
  location: class CopyCharacters
```

I'm doing practice from this [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html), Now as i run my program using intellij idea IDE it's giving me this error..

and here is my source code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class CopyCharacters {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        FileReader inputstream=null;
        FileWriter outputstream=null;

        try{
            inputstream=new FileReader("D://raj.txt");
            outputstream=new FileWriter("D://raj1.txt");

            int c;
            while((c=inputstream.read())!=-1){
                outputstream.write(c);
            }
        }finally{
            if(inputstream!=c){
                inputstream.close();
            }
            if(outputstream!=c){
                outputstream.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDITED**:

According to @I wish i could think a good's answer it's working but it's showing new error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ArrayDemo
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)
```

Comment: Declare variable c outside try block

Comment: What has this to do with MySQL?

Comment: You declared variable c inside your try block, and trying to access in  finally block. Move declaration outside try block

Comment: I did all according to this [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html)..

Comment: I can't see how the edit is related to the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change you finally block to

```
    }finally{
        if(inputstream!=null){
            inputstream.close();
        }
        if(outputstream!=null){
            outputstream.close();
        }
    }
```

why would you compare a stream to an int?

After doing this, you will find that you can keep your declaration of `c` as it is.

Comment: Thanks .. finally it's working but there is a new error pls resolve my issue you almost there... pls see my edit :)

Comment: where is `ArrayDemo` being used.  I can not see it in your code.

Comment: Ohh i guess that's an IDE problem... i'm using intellij idea.. first time, i've created a project before for ArrayDemo, so i delete that program and made a new class over it... i guess that's why i'm getting this//

Comment: What IDE do you prefer for java?

Answer (score 0):

move int c; to outside try block

```
import java.io.*;

public class CopyCharacters {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        FileReader inputstream=null;
        FileWriter outputstream=null;
int c=0;

        try{
            inputstream=new FileReader("D://raj.txt");
            outputstream=new FileWriter("D://raj1.txt");

            //int c;
            while((c=inputstream.read())!=-1){
                outputstream.write(c);
            }
        }finally{
            if(inputstream!=c){
                inputstream.close();
            }
            if(outputstream!=c){
                outputstream.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i did as you said now it's showing this error : `Error:(18, 27) java: incomparable types: java.io.FileReader and int`
`Error:(21, 28) java: incomparable types: java.io.FileWriter and int`

Comment: Why are you comparing an `int` to a `FileReader`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am not comparing int to filereader,I have just answered the original question (symbol c not found).Comaring filreader with int is OP's another issue.I have not answered to this issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would try and compare a `int` with `Reader`

```
if(inputstream!=c){
```

They are incompatible and can't be compared, it doesn't make sense.

Because you're using Java 1.8, you could take advantage of the [`try-with-resource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) feature, which will automatically close your streams, for example...

```
try (FileReader inputstream = new FileReader("D://raj.txt")) {
    try (FileWriter outputstream = new FileWriter("D://raj1.txt")) {
        int c;
        while ((c = inputstream.read()) != -1) {
            outputstream.write(c);
        }
    } finally {
    }
} finally {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you declare your variable C in TRY block. which can not be accessed outside TRY. And here you access that in Finally block which gives you error. Declare int c globally.